# Determining if an order pattern in nodes is followed with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, unordered, flwor

I have the xml code below with 4 `<e>` nodes, and I need to create a XQuery procedure to which I pass 2 parameters (even 3) param1=EP, param2=PRF and determined which nodes `<e>` present the nodes in that order EP before PRF. After that reprint the same structure but with the  node must have a new attribute called ordered with the value yes or no `<e ordered="yes">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
<e>
<element sign="none;isroot:yes">
    <e_afl>kamatsa</e_afl><e_asl>crawl</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal">
    <e_afl>vai</e_afl><e_asl>DUR</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>t</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ak</e_afl><e_asl>PRF</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>i</e_afl><e_asl>REAL</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal">
    <e_afl>na</e_afl><e_asl>1SG.O</e_asl>
</element>
</e>
<e>
<element sign="none">
    <e_afl>i</e_afl><e_asl>3m.A</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal;isroot:yes">
    <e_afl>pos</e_afl><e_asl>hit</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>a</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>vai</e_afl><e_asl>DUR</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ve</e_afl><e_asl>FRUS</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>t</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ak</e_afl><e_asl>PRF</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>a</e_afl><e_asl>REAL</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal">
    <e_afl>na</e_afl><e_asl>1SG.O</e_asl>
</element>
</e>
<e>
<element sign="none">
    <e_afl>y</e_afl><e_asl>3m.A</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal;isroot:yes">
    <e_afl>aNt</e_afl><e_asl>work</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>vai</e_afl><e_asl>DUR</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>t</e_afl><e_asl>PRF</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ak</e_afl><e_asl>CAUS.SOC</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ak</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>i</e_afl><e_asl>REAL</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal">
    <e_afl>ri</e_afl><e_asl>3m.O</e_asl>
</element>
</e>
<e>
<element sign="none">
    <e_afl>n</e_afl><e_asl>1SG.S</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="equal;isroot:yes">
    <e_afl>aNt</e_afl><e_asl>work</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>a</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>vai</e_afl><e_asl>DUR</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>t</e_afl><e_asl>EP</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>ak</e_afl><e_asl>PRF</e_asl>
</element>
<element sign="hyphen">
    <e_afl>i</e_afl><e_asl>REAL</e_asl>
</element>
</e>
</results>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what XQuery processor are you using (especially interesting is whether the processor supports XQuery Update. Without that, updating an element is not possible, you have to recreate it).

Comment: I am using BaseX 7.8.2 for Windows which supports XQuery 3.0 http://basex.org/products/xquery/

Comment: The important part is not XQuery Update, which is another standard than XQuery 3.0. But BaseX supports that as well, so you are good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseX supports [XQuery Update](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates). It also has a nice (at the moment still implementation-specific, but an issue is currently pending at the W3C for standardization) operator called `update`, simplifying transform expressions.

Please note that your XML is currently not well-formed as XML documents always have a single root element. Provided you add this, the following should work:

```
for $e in doc("your-xml-file.xml")//e
return
  if ($e/element[e_asl = "EP"][following-sibling::element/e_asl = "PRF"])
  then $e update insert node (attribute {"ordered"} {"yes"}) into .
  else $e
```

By the way, if you want to modify your original database, you can issue the following command

```
SET WRITEBACK true
```

(or start BaseX using the command line and the `-u` command)
and execute the following:

```
for $e in doc("e.xml")//e[element[e_asl = "EP"][following-sibling::element/e_asl = "PRF"]]
return insert node (attribute {"ordered"} {"yes"}) into $e
```